# Como obtener la longitud de un arreglo en Kotlin, pero solo los espacios que están siendo utilizados?

Tags: android, android-studio, array, kotlin, arraylist

En un activity estoy iniciando un arrayList

`var arrayJugador = Array<String>(7){""}`

Tiene longitud 7 que es el numero maximo de personas que se pueden ingresar, pero esto puede ser de 2 a 8 jugadores, en otro activity necesito obtener la longitud pero solo de los arreglos que no estén vacíos

```
textviwejugadore?.text = lista?.size.toString()
```

pero esto siempre me da 7, que es el tamaño que ya le estoy dando por defecto, como puedo obtener la longitud o el numero de espacios utilizados del arreglo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para esto hay una función llamada `count`

```
textviwejugadore?.text = lista?.count { it.isNotEmpty() }.toString()
```

también podes usar `filter`

```
textviwejugadore?.text = lista?.filter { it.isNotEmpty() }.size.toString()
```

Por cierto, esto `Array<String>(7){""}` no es un arrayList. Es simplemente un array. Un ArrayList puede cambiar de tamaño.

```
val jugadores = mutableListOf<String>()
jugadores.size // esto es 0
jugadores.add("player 1")
jugadores.size // ahora es 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas definiendo e inicializando un array este no podra ser modificado, en este caso siempre tendra una medida de 7 elementos.

```
 var arrayJugador = Array<String>(7){""}
 println("medida: " +arrayJugador.size)
```

salida:

```
medida: 7
```

Debes usar un [ArrayList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/) en el cual puedes agregar o eliminar elementos.

```
val arrayJugador = arrayListOf<String>()
arrayJugador.addAll(listOf("Jesus", "Mary","Jorge"))
println(arrayJugador) 
println("Elementos: " +arrayJugador.size)

//Agrega nuevo elemento.
arrayJugador.add("Elena")
println(arrayJugador) 
println("Elementos: " +arrayJugador.size)

//Elimina elemento definido por el indice
arrayJugador.removeAt(2)
println(arrayJugador) 
println("Elementos: " +arrayJugador.size)
```

Salida:

```
[Jesus, Mary, Jorge]
Elementos: 3
[Jesus, Mary, Jorge, Elena]
Elementos: 4
[Jesus, Mary, Elena]
Elementos: 3
```